# How do I resolve Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support' available in SDK installer

Tags: android, xamarin

Ok so I've been stuck on this one for a few days now.  I have gone through all the posts and nothing has worked yet.  I have a vanilla cross platform Xamarin Forms Portable solution which will not build.  I have used Nuget Package Manager to update the following packages to the latest version available:

I can not get the Xamarin Forms to update to v2.3.3.180.  I end up getting 34 build errors starting with "Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users[userid]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\24.2.1\content./ doesn't exist.

No Google results whatsoever for package 'Xamarin.Android.Support'.  This package actually doesn't exist.  The closest package to this name is Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 which is already referenced.  I have tried deleting the zip files and even the entire Xamarin directory multiple times, also deleted the bin and obj directories, clean and rebuild, still no cigar.  I have also used Android SDK Manager to download Android Support Repository.  I have even tried manually downloading the https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r38.zip and extracting it.

The error message itself is misleading because there is no package with this exact name.  I was having similar issues prior to this using earlier versions of the package at which point I thought lets try using the latest version of all packages referenced.  I more thing to try

I am going to download the https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r38.zip
and not extract it as the error messages suggest but rather rename it 29EB87B0770A1740E6766163D3BFCB8B.zip

I am convinced that at the root of the problem is the corrupt zip file.  Even deleting it repeatedly has not led to the zip file ever being more than 3Kb when it should be 200+Mb.  So lets see if I get Lucky if not then I could use some help.  This is my first question on StackOverflow :) I'm a late bloomer and you guys have done all the hard work for me :)  thanks!

this is the first time i see it taking a while to build.  so this is progress.  plus i was out of c drive space no resolved so its still building will keep you posted.  sorry for the multiple edits on this.  the error message is very misleading in that it says to download the zip file and extract it but it should not be extracted, it should be downloaded and renamed.  (i think).

REBUILD ALL SUCCEEDED!!!  HELL YEAH!  I'm going home!

Comment: Have you seen this document? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/

Comment: If you found a solution, which it seems like from your post, the please post your solution as an answer and accept it. It may help others.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so now we know why everyone is getting the zip package failure.  The most probable reason is that we are all using corporate firewalls in our case (WebSense) and we have no problem downloading the zip file using Internet Explorer.  This is because the proxy server is configured to allow downloads from internet explorer.  When we build the Xamarin solution Visual Studio connects to the web proxy but the web proxy is NOT configured to allow Visual Studio download permissions.  So we are now in the process of adding an exception rule to the proxy server to allow access to https://dl-ssl.google.com

I will keep you posted on the full solution and will detail it here.  I will also detail how to determine the name of the zip file using ildasm.  I saw some other people already figured it out so I will reference this.  I will be in and out of work for the next few days while I deal with my medical condition but rest assured I will post a fully detailed answer.  For now just download the zip file manually and rename it.

I will update this answer soon will more detail and hopefully we will also be seeing the end of the dreaded corrupt zip file :)

feel free to reach me directly if you require further détails asap.